# says run time error 1004 unable to set the orientation property of the pivotfield class

Tags: excel, vba

Having issues on the below code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WeekNumIss").Orientation = _
    xlHidden
```

says run time error 1004 unable to set the orientation property of the pivotfield class

please help how to remove it. Thanks! :(

```
Sub fixblanks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dash").Activate

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("IssueMonth"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("IssueMonth"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IssueMonth"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("IssueMonth"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("IssueMonth"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("IssueMonth"). _
        ClearAllFilters
        
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WeekNumIss").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
        
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("IssueMonth")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("WeekNumIss").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
        
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("IssueMonth")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("WeekNumIss").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
        
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IssueMonth")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("WeekNumIss").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
        
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("IssueMonth")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("WeekNumIss").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
        
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("IssueMonth")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("WeekNumIss").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
        
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("IssueMonth")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
        
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is saying that Excel can't find `WeekNumIss` in `PivotTable1`.
There are a few reasons this may be:

1. I see you are using `ActiveSheet` in your code. If `PivotTable1` isn't in the active sheet then you will get this error. Instead, you could use `Sheets([SheetName])`
2. `WeekNumIss` isn't included in the Rows, Columns, or Filter section of `PivotTable1`.
3. The name `WeekNumIss` or `PivotTable1` doesn't match what is in the workbook exactly.

I hope this helps! If not, please let me know so I can debug a bit more.
A picture of the pivot table in question would be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot ben! I did some quite few changes because of number 2 and number 3, and it worked! :)
I'm currently new in macro vba that is why am having this kind of concerns. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Happy to help! I understand the frustrations of buggy code :)